# Applying np.argsort() to an numpy array with repeated elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, np.argsort

What is the order of indexes for each element after applying  np.argsort() to an array  with repeated values?

```
np.argsort(np.array([5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 0, 5, 0, 5, 5, 0, 5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 5, 4, 4, 0, 3, 5, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 1, 0, 2, 5, 0, 5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0, 3, 2, 0, 2, 0]))
```

gives:

```
 [85 33 32 40 45 47 48 54 18 34 16 59 13 38 72 11 83 69 80  5 39 55 19 68 66 52 51 65 70 74 44 43 84 82 53 62 42  7  1 10 29 36 27 26  9 76 60 79 20  6 22 37 50  2 30 41 81 28 25 24 49 58 23 77  3 57 21 78 75  4 73 61 8 67 12 64 63 14 15 56 17 46 31 35 71  0]
```

For example, in the original array,  0 starts as 5th element and then 11th, 13th,...   Why does  the resulted argsort array start by indexes 85, 33, 32, 40, 47,... instead of 5, 11, 13, 16, 18, 32, 33, 34, 38, 40 ...?

Comment: np.argsort uses unstable quicksort (which does not preserve order of it's values), that's why you get such behaviour

Comment: Use `np.argsort(array, kind='stable')`